# Jenkins checkstyle stage error in a pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, devops, checkstyle

I am executing a checkstyle stage in a declarative pipeline and getting the bellow error:

```
+ checkstyle canComputeNew: false, defaultEncoding: , healthy: , pattern: , unHealthy:
```

workspace@tmp/durable-67a8a19c/script.sh: 3:
workspace@tmp/durable-67a8a19c/script.sh: checkstyle: not found

pipeline code for checkstyle

```
stage("code quality"){
     
     steps{
       sh """    
       
       checkstyle canComputeNew: false, defaultEncoding: '', healthy: '', pattern: '', unHealthy: ''
       """
       
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify the plugin on your Jenkins Configuration. Maybe you are using deprecated plugin:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/checkstyle/